# How to pass form data to stripe webhook in Django so it emails them to me once payment's done

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, stripe-payments, webhooks

I'm trying to get my Django app to email order details  to me (name, shipping address, etc.) once my Stripe webhook confirms payment but have no idea how to pass on that data. To webhook? (checkout function redirects to a Stripe server checkout)

buy.html

```
    <form method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="nume">Nume si Prenume</label>
              <input type="text" name="nume" class="form-control" id="nume" required>
         
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="strada">Strada</label>
              <input type="text" name="strada" class="form-control" id="strada" required>
          
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
              <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="telefon">Telefon</label>
              <input type="text" name="telefon" class="form-control" id="telefon" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="cantitate">cantitate</label>
              <input type="number" id="cantitate" name="cantitate" min="1" max="8" required>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send order</button>

  <div class="jumbotron">
  <h1 class="display-3">The Product</h1>
  <p class="lead">Purchase The Product for only $99.</p>
  <a href="#" id="buy_now_btn" class="btn btn-primary">Buy Now</a>
</div>

<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>

<script>

  const buy_now_button = document.querySelector('#buy_now_btn')

  buy_now_button.addEventListener('click', event => {
    fetch('/checkout/')
    .then((result) => { return result.json() })
    .then((data) => {
      var stripe = Stripe(data.stripe_public_key);

      stripe.redirectToCheckout({
     
        sessionId: data.session_id
      }).then(function (result) {
        
      });
    })
  })
</script>
```

I already have a working email function set up and can call it with

```
sendemail('sample@outlook.com', 'subject', email_content)
```

And also got how to extract the data from the .html form.

Just don't know how to send email with that data once stripe_webhook fires

views.py

```
from .sendemail import sendemail

def index(request):
return render(request, 'store/buy.html')



@csrf_exempt
def checkout(request):

session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
    payment_method_types=['card'],
    line_items=[{
        'price': 'price_########' ,
        'quantity': 1,
    }],
    mode='payment',
    success_url=request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('success')) + '?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
    cancel_url=request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('buy')),
)

return JsonResponse({
    'session_id' : session.id,
    'stripe_public_key' : settings.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY
})




@csrf_exempt
def stripe_webhook(request):

print('WEBHOOK!')

endpoint_secret = '############'

payload = request.body
sig_header = request.META['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE']
event = None

try:
    event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
        payload, sig_header, endpoint_secret
    )
except ValueError as e:
    # Invalid payload
    return HttpResponse(status=400)
except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
    # Invalid signature
    return HttpResponse(status=400)

# Handle the checkout.session.completed event
if event['type'] == 'checkout.session.completed':
    session = event['data']['object']
    print(session)
    line_items = stripe.checkout.Session.list_line_items(session['id'], limit=1)
    print(line_items)

return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

Comment: A CheckoutSession completes asynchronously. You would want to trigger your email sending as part of the [fulfillment steps](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders) which is part of the webhook endpoint.

Comment: @taintedzodiac  Do you reckon it would be safe to use sessions to pass that information on from one view to the  webhook view?  (there's no mention on how to actually do this in the fulfillment steps) Thank you

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but I wouldn't expose any sensitive information to the frontend (keep the data on the backend and only pass it locally and via HTTPS/SSL when necessary).